# mysql two table with different record in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to show how many billing_amount has be done by particular user on that target month? 
I have two tables, one is target and the other is closure_emp.

```
SELECT fk_user_id,target_month,target 
FROM `target` 
WHERE fk_user_id='31' and target_month > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

This shows 6 records

```
fk_user_id     target_month  target 
31           2013-08-01  100000
31           2013-09-01  100000
31           2013-10-01  120000
31           2013-11-01  120000
31           2013-12-01  120000
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM `closure_employee` 
WHERE ce_recruiter_id='31' and offer_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
```

This shows 2 records

```
  user_id billing_amount offer_date     joining_date    
    31     390000     2013-08-30    2-09-2013
    31     208354     2013-09-30    25-11-2013
```

I need a query to show both the table in one as below

```
 fk_user_id  target_month    target  user_id  billing_amount
    31      2013-08-01   100000   31          390000
    31      2013-09-01   100000   31          208354
    31      2013-10-01   120000   31            null
    31      2013-11-01   120000   31            null
    31      2013-12-01   120000   31            null
```

Please help me.

Comment: How do you know which `billing_amount` corresponds to which `target_month`?

Comment: i am showing last 6 month record from both the table with specific user id

Comment: That doesn't not answer the question. Unless you have a `target_month` field in the second query result, how do you know that `390000` belongs to `2013-08-01`?

Comment: This doesn't really answer @Bibhas question. Your missing essential information imho in `closure_employee`, because you can't link any of the billing amounts to a specific month. And to draw the assumption that every `target` month will match cannot be done from the information provided.

Comment: sorry @Bibhas and nietonfir i have two column in closure_emp that is offer_date and joining_date but i need to show record from offer_date.
if my ans is still not correct please help me

Comment: In the second query, show us more values from `closure_emp` that has the column `offer_date`. You need to check if the `offer_date` belongs to the `target_month`

Comment: @Bibhas i have updated the second query result to show offer_date and joining_date i need to show the result as par target month and offer_Date. every user have it's monthly target and the target is set on 1st date of every month and the offer_Date can be done any date of that target month. so i have to show the user_id with target ,target_month and billing amount and offer date.
if required i can show the hole table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can get the result by using a `LEFT JOIN` between your tables.   Since you want to return all rows from the `target` table you will then `LEFT JOIN` the `closure_employee` table on the `user_id`.

In order to assign the correct `billing_amount` to each row from `target`, you will need to use the `month()` value for the `target_month` and the `offer_date` - This will also be part of your join condition.

The query will be similar to the following:

```
select t.fk_user_id,
  t.target_month,
  t.target,
  e.user_id,
  e.billing_amount
from target t
left join closure_employee e
  on t.fk_user_id = e.user_id
  and month(t.target_month) = month(e.offer_date)
  and e.offer_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
where t.target_month > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fed45/5).  You'll notice that the `offer_date` filter to return the previous 7 months, has been added to the join condition instead of the where clause - doing this will still return the rows from the `closure_employee` in that timeframe, but it will also return all rows from your `target` table which appears to be the behavior that you want.

If you need to add the filter by the `ce_recruiter_id` and the `fk_user_id` then you would alter the above query to:

```
select t.fk_user_id,
  t.target_month,
  t.target,
  e.user_id,
  e.billing_amount
from target t
left join closure_employee e
  on t.fk_user_id = e.user_id
  and month(t.target_month) = month(e.offer_date)
  and e.offer_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
  and e.ce_recruiter_id='31'
where t.target_month > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  and t.fk_user_id='31'
```

Comment: I am very happy that u reply to my question. with all respect Thank you so much.
i am trying for morning to solve this issue as i am not good at mysql.

Comment: as i am running this query to local phpmysql it is showing the correct result but when i run this query on my server phpmysql then i am getting null value form all the closure_employee table.
please provide some solution. thanx

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT 
     t1.fk_user_id, t1.target_month, t1.target, t2.billing_amount 
 FROM 
     target AS t1, closure_employee AS t2
 WHERE 
     t1.fk_user_id = 31 AND t2.user_id = 31
     AND
     t1.target_month > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

Hope that helps (and works - is off top of my head!

This is assuming that fk_user_id = user_id for your query

You should also check out how to use JOIN on a table -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

however you might want to start with a simpler example to get your head around it!

Comment: sorry @Graham Ritchie this is showing all the record.as par my knowledge it required  sub-queries but i do't no how?

Comment: ammended answer - I have just asked the database to match all records instead of a specific one.

Comment: try SELECT DISTINCT - without live data (and while on a mobile) I am obviously being thick!

Comment: Hope someone else weighs in for you - already got 1 downvote - not getting more for being a dumb-ass! - I am obviously being a ickle bit thick today - I can see no reason for duplicate entries